# Why am I getting this extra part in retreiving the route parameter (URL) in Javascript with ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-visualization

I am using Google Charts with ASP.NET WebForms and I was able to add interactivity (drill-down feature) to Google Pie chart. However, I am struggling right now in getting the right URL for the page that the user will be redirected to when he/she clicks on any part of the chart. 
I was able to get the URL and redirect the user to the page, but there is an extra part in the URL and I don't know from where it is coming.

Here's the code:

```
function selectHandler() {
                var selectedItem = pieChart.getSelection()[0];

                if (selectedItem) {
                    var topping = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
                    var url = '<%= Page.GetRouteUrl("TweetsByRouteId", HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString()) %>';
                    window.open(url + topping);
                }
```

Kindly note that I am ASP.NET URL Routing. I think the issue is with the line:

```
var url = '<%= Page.GetRouteUrl("TweetsByRouteId", HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString()) %>';
```

The returned value of this function is:

> http://localhost:49953/Dashboard/Tweets/5?Length=1Negative

And the desired returned value should be:

> http://localhost:49953/Dashboard/Tweets/5#Negative

**So how can I fix this issue?**

Comment: Could you, please provide the value of `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString()` and `HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString()` separately?

Comment: Hi @ViktorOleksyshyn, here are the answers: `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString()` returns the original url of the page that contains chart, which I don't need it: **http://localhost:49953/Dashboard/TestDashboard3/5** and `HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values[‌​"id"].ToString()` returns the value of Id (or querystring) which is **5**